# Spring boot app caching TLS handshake to do not drop after 30 seconds

Tags: java, swift, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I have a spring boot application and would like to force a TLS session resumption so that
the application is communicating with a IOS (Swift) phone. I noticed that after not using the phone for a while (30 seconds), the first request takes more time because the SSL handshake is performed.
On the Swift part, I would to know if there is any API which could configure my URLSession object such that the TLS handshake is cached between two requests for a long period of time.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("jdk.tls.useExtendedMasterSecret", "false");
    System.setProperty("jdk.tls.allowLegacyResumption", "false");
    System.setProperty("jdk.tls.server.enableSessionTicketExtension", "true");
    System.setProperty("jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation", "true");
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");


    new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .beanNameGenerator(new CustomGenerator())
            .run(args);

}
```

This is what I see in the logs after the request after 30 seconds.
could I do something on Java side or on Swift side to increase this timeout of 30 seconds ?

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|21|XNIO-1 I/O-5|2021-07-14 17:47:37.294 EEST|Alert.java:232|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "warning",
  "description": "close_notify"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|21|XNIO-1 I/O-5|2021-07-14 17:47:37.295 EEST|SSLEngineImpl.java:743|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
```

Comment: "to know if there is any API which could configure my URLSession object such that the TLS handshake is cached between two requests for a long period of time."  If there is one, it should be listed under `URLSession` in the doc, don't you think?  So what is your actual question?  You've looked but don't know which one to use?

Comment: Maybe I can do something server side  ?